# When is the center of group contained in the derived subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, direct-product, derived-subgroup

Let $N$ be a group. **Assume that $N$ is torsion-free, finitely generated and nilpotent.** I read somewhere that
$$ Z(N) \subset [N,N] \iff N \text{ cannot be written as a direct product of groups } N = A \times B \text{ where }A \text{ is non-trivial abelian.}$$
One implication is clear to me: $\implies$. I prove it by contraposition: assume $N$ can be decomposed as $A\times B$ where $A$ is non-trivial abelian. Then it is clear that $$ Z(N) = Z(A) \times Z(B) = A\times Z(B).$$
On the other hand, we have that
$$ [N,N] = [A,A] \times [B,B] = \{1\} \times [B,B].$$
If we had that $Z(N) \subset [N,N]$, we would need that $A\subset \{1\}$, which is clearly not possible as $A$ was non-trivial. So by contraposition, we have proven the first implication.

---

**Now my problem is with the other implication.** I don't know how I can prove the converse. I don't even know how to go about doing that. My gut suggests contraposition again, but then I have to use the assumption that $Z(N) \not\subset [N,N]$ to somehow construct a direct product decomposition of $N$ which has a non-trivial abelian factor, and I don't see how I can go about doing something like that.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** I added the assumptions that $N$ is torsion-free, finitely generated and nilpotent. These are the only groups I am interested in in the context of my research.

Comment: I suggest that you consider the possibility that the result you are trying to prove is not true, and look for a counterexample.

Comment: Hi @DerekHolt, thank you for your response! I can't seem to find a counterexample. Moreover, I am in fact only interested in groups that are finitely generated, nilpotent and torsion-free. I edited my question to reflect this. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Keep looking (3-generated 2-step nilpotent groups).

Comment: I suspect the statement is correct if you replace $[G,G]$ with $\sqrt[G]{[G,G]}$, i.e. the set $\{ g \in G \mid \exists n \in \mathbb{N}: g^n \in [G,G] \}$. That could also be a hint on finding/constructing a counterexample to the original statement...

Comment: It is still not true for torsion-free finitely generated nilpotent groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This claim does **not** hold. A counterexample (even in the realm of finitely generated, torsion-free and nilpotent groups) is that of the Heisenberg group $H$ of upper triangular $3\times 3$-matrices with entries in $2\mathbb{Z}$. It can easily be seen that in this case
$$ Z(H) \not\subset [H,H].$$
Yet, it is easy to check that $H$ does not have any abelian factor.

The claim *can* however be proven for groups that are nilpotent, torsion-free and **radicable.** This has to do with Mal'cev completions and the correspondence between Mal'cev completions and rational Lie algebras.